# Interchanging finite union of finite intersection of sets

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I would like to exchange the set operation :

$$\cup_{i=1}^m\cap_{j=1}^{n_i} A_{i,j}$$ to be $$\cap \cup A_{i,j}$$ but it is a bit confusing to keep track of the index, and deduce the formula. Compare to summation case $$\sum_i \sum_j = \sum_j \sum_i$$ in finite sum case. I think interchanging $\cup, \cap$ might not be the same as interchanging $\sum \sum$.

Can anyone provide the way to see the formula to interchanging $$\cup \cap \ \mbox{to} \ \cap \cup $$ of the set $A_{i,j}$ above.

Thank you.

---

Here is the actual problem I would like to solve : Define
$$G = \{\sqcup_{i=1}^m\ (\cap_{j=1}^{n_i} A_{i,j}) |\ \mbox{either} \ A_{i,j} \ \mbox{or} \ A_{i,j}^c \in \scr{C}\}$$ where $\scr{C}$ is a given non-empty collection of sets. ($\sqcup$ indicate disjoint union operation)

I would like to show that $G$ is an algebra. I struck with the step that if $A \in G$, then $A^c \in G$ which involving interchanging union and intersection. (Actually, I have to show that $G = A(\scr{C})$ (the algebra generated by $\scr{C}).$

Comment: Which def'n of disjoint union are you using? For the disjoint union of $A$ and $B,$ I use $(A\times \{0\}) \cup (B\times \{1\})$.

Comment: @user254665 I use $$A \sqcup B = A \cup B \  \mbox{with} \ A \cap B = \phi$$

Answer (score 2):

In general, you cannot exchange unions and intersections. To compare with your other example, it looks more like exchanging a sum and a product than two sums...

Comment: I add the detail of the actual problem I have to solve under the question. It might turn out that my approach to this question is not appropriate, and I do not need to interchange union and intersection.